# Обращение к классам

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли обратится по отдельности к второму, третьему и четвертому "skill"?

Comment: Можно. Но для начала замените картинку текстом (под постом кнопка "Править")

Comment: Хотя бы мельком пройдитесь "обучалкам" CSS.. [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

Answer (score 0):

как варианты:

```
skill:nth-child(1) {}
```

либо:

```
skill:nth-child(2) {}
```

либо:

```
skill:not(last-child) {}
```